Can Rufus create a bootable USB from a qemu raw image?
As the title - I have a raw image file created by qemu-img, and I need an ISO file (preferred option, for use as a VPS) or a bootable USB stick (if I can't get a file).
Rufus reads the .img file without complaining, and writes to the USB. However, the USB doesn't appear to be bootable. Rufus has created 3 partitions. Ubuntu's disk-tool shows these as BIOS boot, Ext 4, and LVM2, but I can't boot on two different laptops.
I've done various checks with Windows tools and these aren't showing the USB as bootable. Disk management, for example, shows the first partition (and the others) as a primary partition, and not an 'EFI system partition'. I'm thinking that the USB should be a single partition anyway, and not 3: it just looks more-or-less like the KVM original.
If I can't do this with Rufus, can anyone suggest another way to get a bootable ISO from a raw file?

Did you try alternatives such as YUMI?

I think the short answer is - no. ISO is a primitive file-level filesystem, while a QEMU raw image is exactly that - a disk image. To extract file-level data from a Linux disk image, you have to understand the partition table, and every possible file system, and you potentially have to decrypt at-rest encrypted disk blocks. This is way beyond a burning app, and completely unrelated to dd, and is what Linux is for. And, if you decoded LUKS blocks, for example, you'd have plain-text files on the ISO image, which is not good. It's a pity that the Rufus docs dont point any of this out.
